# Selecting multiple columns in R wide data to pipe an operation

Tags: r, recode

I have a data in wide format.e.g.

```r
dt <- (age, gender, income, EDU1990, EDU1991, EDU1992, EDU1993, EDU1994, EDU1995 ..... EDU2021)
```

I am trying to select all the column with EDU and recode the variables in all of them at once. I tried to use the grep function but it is not working. Example :

```r
grep(^EDU, dt) %>%
  mutate(EDU = recode(^EDU, "highschool"=1, "college"=2)
```

Is there an easier/better way to select these multiple columns and pipe a function at once?

Comment: Welcome to SO, rais! It can be difficult at times trying to help a question when the code is incomplete, usually just trying for "brevity". In this case, it isn't clear if `dt` is a `list` or `data.frame` or similar, nor if you are literally using `grep(^EDU` versus `grep("^EDU"`. Further, `grep` is going to return integers (or `integer(0)`), not a `data.frame` that `dplyr::mutate` expects. Please consider filling out the question a bit to make it self-contained and reproducible with minimal sample data and syntactically correct code. Thanks!

Comment: Some links that provide good discussion and examples of how to do that include: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the welcome. I just started here so I will make sure I will try harder to better frame my question next time :)

Comment: @r2evans I just tried to frame my question better here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672373/selecting-large-number-of-columns-for-recoding-the-variable-values . Thank you for the comments and guidance !

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('EDU'),  ~recode(., "highschool"=1, "college"=2)))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. It did not work and I think it might be because I did not frame my question correctly. Here is my 2nd attempt to frame my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672373/selecting-large-number-of-columns-for-recoding-the-variable-values Your help would be appreciated !