# Selecting large number of columns for recoding the variable values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to recode a group of variables in a dataframe(wide format). Let's say in that dataframe, I have a variable - "Education status" which runs from month 1 to 150, labeled as EDU1, EDU2, EDU3 .... EDU150 across 150 columns. The variable has values = 0,1,2,3,4,5,NA. I am trying to recode the variables (0=91,1=92,2=93,3,4,5=94) while keeping NA as it is. Since it is a large number of columns, I am trying to do it at once. This is what I tried.

First selecting columns from EDU1 to EDU150 at once.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 mutate_at(c(EDU1:EDU150),
 ~recode(.,"0=91;1=92,2=93;3=94;4=94;5=94"))
```

Another way I tried is picking up a part of the column name i.e starts with 'EDU'and specifying where to run the recode function.

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
mutate(across(starts_with('EDU'), ~ recode(.,"0=91;1=92,2=93;3=94;4=94;5=94")))
```

None of this work, and I get an error saying

> Unreplaced values treated as NA as.x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default

Can anyone help me with this? Is it because I have some NA values in the variables I am working at or something is wrong with the code.
What would be the best way to run a function selecting a large number of columns by picking up the column name?

Comment: Please consider to post a small reproducible example with `dput` and your expected output i..e `dput(head(df[, 1:10]))`

Comment: @rais, go back to your previous question and please read my comments and read the links I sent regarding making *reproducible questions*. Of note, and repeated by akrun here, please give us usable data. `dput(.)` is really the best way for many questions, let's just stick with that.

Comment: Thanks @akrun and r2evans. I am working on a secure sever with the dataset and can't copy/paste from there. Any leads on producing the reproducible data in such situation?  Thanks !

Comment: @rais I already showed the code i.e. `dput(head(df[, 1:10]))` which gives the first 6 rows for 1st 10 columns.   if `df` is the dataset and assuming you read the data in `R` with `df <- read.csv('yourfile.csv')`

Comment: @akrun - Yes i get that. my question was if i am working with data on a secure server, I cannot copy the output. so how do people show the sample data? Sorry new here so trying to learn

Comment: @rais I would say check the `str(df)`, create a small dummy dataset based on the column type etc, and dput that dummy with expected ouptut

Comment: @akrun Thank you ! Will try that

Comment: @rais: in that case (I've run into that too), then *make fake data*. Only you know what the data looks like, what its classes are, what the relationships are (if any) between columns, etc. You know what it should be, and you can likely generate *something* without too much effort. While you and I are both capable of making fake data, the chance of my fake data being truly representative of the real data is low ... and to be honest, it really is encumbent on the asker to include as many details as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    EDU1:EDU150,
    ~ recode(
      .x,
      `0` = 91L,
      `1` = 92L,
      `2` = 93L,
      `3` = 94L,
      `4` = 94L,
      `5` = 94L
    )
  ))
```

Comment: In R, `0 = '91'` is not legal syntax, you should see the error `unexpected '=' in "dplyr::recode(.x, 0="`. At the very least, enclose the LHS numbers in strings. (Yes, it would help immensely if the OP included sample data.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I've edited my answer. Now It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Another question - I have another group of variable (large number), let's say from 6,7,8,9 ...50 and I want to recode it to 95, what would be the best way to select it at once. I tried this but did not work                 
 library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    EDU1:EDU150,
    ~ recode(
      .x,
      `0` = 91L,
      `1` = 92L,
      `2` = 93L,
      `3` = 94L,
      `4` = 94L,
      `5` = 94L,
       `6:50` = 95L
    )
  ))

Comment: You can use a `case_when` statement instead of `recode`  like this `df %>%
  mutate(across(
    EDU1:EDU150,
    ~ case_when(
      .x == 0 ~ 91,
      .x == 1 ~ 92,
      .x == 2 ~ 93,
      .x %in% (3:5) ~ 94,
      .x %in% (6:50) ~ 95
    )
  ))
`